# Ionic capacitor 3 with offline mode error

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

I have this error when turn off wifi and click login page, I mean I have check network status to make sure if network disconnected alert will show up but I got this issue and alert not showing up.

```
1. zone.js:2680          POST net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED

Button.handleClick @ ion-button_2.entry.js:165
zone.js:1061 Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isProxied') ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isProxied')
  
NgForm_submit_HostBindingHandler @ forms.js:4139
executeListenerWithErrorHandling @ core.js:15327
wrapListenerIn_markDirtyAndPreventDefault @ core.js:15365
(anonymous) @ platform-browser.js:561
invokeTask @ zone.js:406
onInvokeTask @ core.js:28679
invokeTask @ zone.js:405
runTask @ zone.js:178
invokeTask @ zone.js:487
invokeTask @ zone.js:1648
globalCallback @ zone.js:1679
globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone.js:1712
Button.handleClick @ ion-button_2.entry.js:165
index-b3eecb14.js:2015 ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-alert_entry_js failed.
(error: http://172.25.20.65:8100/node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-alert_entry_js.js)
  
LoginPage_Template_form_ngSubmit_14_listener @ template.html:22
executeListenerWithErrorHandling @ core.js:15327
wrapListenerIn_markDirtyAndPreventDefault @ core.js:15365
__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:183
next @ Subscriber.js:122
_next @ Subscriber.js:72
next @ Subscriber.js:49
next @ Subject.js:39
emit @ core.js:25955
onSubmit @ forms.js:4106
NgForm_submit_HostBindingHandler @ forms.js:4139
executeListenerWithErrorHandling @ core.js:15327
wrapListenerIn_markDirtyAndPreventDefault @ core.js:15365

Show 54 more frames
zone.js:1061 Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isProxied') ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isProxied')
    at index-b3eecb14.js:1702:23
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (asyncToGenerator.js:3:1)
    at _next (asyncToGenerator.js:25:1)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:372:1)
    at Zone.run (zone.js:134:1)
    at zone.js:1275:1
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:406:1)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:178:1)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:585:1) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isProxied')
    at http://172.25.20.65:8100/vendor.js:113156:19
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (http://172.25.20.65:8100/vendor.js:158781:24)
    at _next (http://172.25.20.65:8100/vendor.js:158803:9)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://172.25.20.65:8100/polyfills.js:9841:26)
    at Zone.run (http://172.25.20.65:8100/polyfills.js:9603:43)
    at http://172.25.20.65:8100/polyfills.js:10744:36
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://172.25.20.65:8100/polyfills.js:9875:31)
    at Zone.runTask (http://172.25.20.65:8100/polyfills.js:9647:47)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (http://172.25.20.65:8100/polyfills.js:10054:35)
```

This issue raised after I migrated from cordova to capacitor.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.